# Using sqlalchemy `session` object for bulk insert and update

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using sqlalchemy `session` object for bulk insert and update.

My session object:

```
def get_session():
    engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost/test_db', use_batch_mode=True)
    Session = sessionmaker(engine)
    return Session()
```

I am doing a bulk insert like below-:

```
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute(Tb_model.__table__.insert(), list_of_dict)
```

similarly bulk update:

```
 conn.execute(Tb_model.__table__.update().
where(Tb_model.__table__.c.id == bindparam('b_id')),list_of_dict)
```

How can I use `Session()` for this?

Comment: Can I ask why? AFAIU the session is specifically for use by the ORM to track objects as they are created/pulled/deleted from the database. If you instantiate a lot of objects of the same class before flushing to the database, the ORM does do a bulk insert, but there is just a lot more overhead.

Comment: Actually I am using session object for querying data from database inside my application and hence I am creating a session object when ever I need to query some data and then I close() that session. But for insert() and update() , I am creating a separate connection. It is kind of extra code and breaking the uniformity . Hence I wanted to do using session() itself. As per you, is doing with connection() object is better than session() object?

Comment: Well you can always access then `engine` through the `session` with `session.bind` and execute your bulk queries against that, e.g. `session.bind.execute(...)`. But that is still just a bulk query and any changes made won't be reflected on to objects that already exist in your session.

Comment: Also, the `get_session()` function that you have is a bit of an anti-pattern. You should only do `engine = create_engine(..)` and `Session = sessionmaker(engine)` once for your application and then any time you need a new session instance for a unit of work, just call `Session()`.